# Chi-squared distribution question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Here is a problem that I just cannot figure out how to answer:

$z_1, z_2, \cdots, z_7$ are all independent, and are all normal random variables with $N(0,1)$. What is the probability of this occurring?
$$
P(Z_1^2 + Z_2^2 + Z_3^2) \leq 4.943(Z_4^2 + Z_5^2 + Z_6^2 + Z_7^2) 
$$

Comment: I would make a new variable
$$
X = Z_1^2 +Z_2^2 +Z_3^2 - 4.943(Z_4^2 + Z_5^2 +Z_6^2 +Z_7^2)
$$
And then figure out the probability distribution for $X$. Finally, the problem becomes: What is the probability $P(X<0) $.

Comment: Even more computationally feasible than @MattiP.'s idea: determine the distribution of $X:=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^3Z_i^2}{\sum_{i=4}^7Z_i^2}$, then find $P(X\le4.943)$.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! Does this question require the usage of the chi-squared distribution table?

Comment: You don't need any $\chi^2$ table, but you will need numerical integration; see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment: since a $\chi_\nu^2$ distribution has PDF $\frac{1}{2^{\nu/2}\Gamma(\nu/2)}x^{\nu/2-1}\exp\frac{-x}{2}$ for $x\ge0$, the PDF of $X:=A/B$ with $A:=\sum_{i=1}^3Z_i^2,\,B:=\sum_{i=4}^7Z_i^2$ [is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Derivation)$$\frac{x^{1/2}}{4\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty b^{5/2}\exp\frac{-b(1+x)}{2}db=\frac{15}{4}x^{1/2}(1+x)^{-7/2}$$for $x\ge0$. With $x=\tan^2t$, you can verify as a sanity check that this PDF integrates to $1$:$$\int_0^\infty x^{1/2}(1+x)^{-7/2}dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}2\sin^2t\cos^3tdt=\operatorname{B}(3/2,\,2)=\frac{\Gamma(3/2)\Gamma(2)}{\Gamma(7/2)}=\frac{4}{15}.$$[Finally](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%2815%2F4%29*x%5E%281%2F2%29%2F%281%2Bx%29%5E%287%2F2%29+from+0+to+4.943),$$\int_0^{4.943}\frac{15}{4}x^{1/2}(1+x)^{-7/2}dx\approx0.949991.$$

---

Edit: as @kimchilover notes, this is equivalent to an $F(3,\,4)$-distributed variable being $\le4.943\times\frac34$, so an $F$-distribution table gives the probability as $\approx0.95$.

Comment: I haven't come across in using integration to calculate probabilities... Still in the very early stages of statistics. Is there perhaps a simpler way of solving this problem? Or perhaps an algebraic form that does not necessarily calculate the exact value? Thank you for your help! Sorry it's just that.. I am having trouble understanding it...  (Edit: I have just started learning statistics in my first year of university)

Comment: @JonHeonLee How can they expect you to solve problems involving the Normal distribution if you don't understand PDFs? How did they even define the Normal distribution?

Comment: @J.G. Maybe the student is taught to pattern recognize the ratio of independent chi-squared rvs as having the F distribution, and so on?

Comment: @kimchilover Thanks; added.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. With the F distribution explanation I finally understand. Thank you!!!!